# ON is part of syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to write inner join or outer join without specfying the condition?
Is `ON condition` is part of the syntax of join condition?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? An inner join is not an inner join if it has no condition.

Comment: I think the only join that has no condition is the `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: @JW. `NATURAL JOIN` has no explicit condition either (and therefore no `ON`). But SQL-Server has not implemented Natural joins.

Comment: @ypercube yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 12):

when using the `ANSI SQL-92` syntax, the `ON` keyword is part of the join except for the `cross join` since you don't have a condition for the relationship.

ex.

**INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB
       on tableA.ID = tableB.ID
```

**CROSS JOIN**

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA CROSS JOIN tableB
```

`ON` should be followed after the joined table (joins like ***INNER and OUTER***) so you won't have syntax error. but if you're using the `ANSI SQL-89` syntax, `ON` keyword is omitted but you have to specify the relationship on the `where clause`

ex.

**INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.ID = tableB.ID
```

**CROSS JOIN**

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA, tableB
```

it is prone to error because if you forget the condition, it won't generate syntax error and will likely do the `cross join`

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't have to specify the `ON`, you could do so in a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA, tableB
WHERE tableA.Id = tableB.Id
```

but this is prone to error (easy to end up with `CROSS JOIN`s) and is generally frowned upon.  See [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) for arguments against it.

**EDIT**: To be more precise, you can `JOIN` using the old style syntax shown above, which doesn't require an `ON`, but if you explicitly join using `INNER | LEFT | FULL` etc. then *yes*, `ON` is part of the syntax.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) page with the precise syntax requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an implicit join without using the join-on syntax:

```
select a.fred, b.joe from tableApple as a, tableBread as b
where a.key1 = b.key1
```

But I'm pretty certain on is required for explicit joins. You will get an incorrect syntax error.
Explicit join meaning:

```
select a.fred, b.joe 
from tableApple as a
left join tableBread as b
on a.key1 = b.key1
where a.key1 = 'sally'
```