# SQL - Joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to grasp the topic of joining tables in SQL.  I know there are multiple joins but not sure which to implement here:

Here is my SQL line in php:

```
$sql=mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM comments 
WHERE item_id = '{$item_id}' 
   AND review > '' 
ORDER BY good DESC, rate_id ASC");
```

This is what I want to join with: Another table called "users".  *"users" and "comments" both have a column called "user_id" to join.*  I want to associate those two to find the full "username" in the users table.

**I know SELECT** is not best practice; but for the sake of this demo, can you include that here?  I also know MySQL injection possibilities to watch for. **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to use the `ANSI SQL-92` format rather than `ANSI SQL-89`. Try this one:

```
SELECT a.* , b.*
FROM comments a
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE item_id = '{$item_id}'  AND 
      review > '' 
ORDER BY good DESC, rate_id ASC
```

**[Good Definition of JOINs](http://mysqljoin.com/)** 
**[Read something here: INNER JOIN (ANSI SQL-89 vs ANSI SQL-92)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768715/491243)**

Additional Information:

Since you are using PHP for this, I'll also recommend to use [**PHP PDO Technology**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

an example for that is:

```
<?php


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT a.* , b.*
    FROM comments a
            INNER JOIN users b
                ON a.user_id = b.user_id
    WHERE item_id = ?  AND 
          review > ? 
    ORDER BY good DESC, rate_id ASC");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $item_id);
$stmt->bindParam(2, '');
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this and for learning joins see [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

```
SELECT c.* , u.*
FROM comments c
     INNER JOIN users u
         ON c.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE item_id = '{$item_id}' 
      AND review > '' 
ORDER BY good DESC, rate_id ASC;
```