# Join in MYSQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to fetch data from three tables that are `Products`, `Attributes` and `features`
One product may have multiple features and attributes

I am using query

```
select * 
from products p, features f, attributes a 
where p.id =1 and p.id = f.id and p.id = a.id
```

I want to know if the query is ok ???

Comment: If a product have no attributes or no features. Should the product still show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `ANSI SQL-89` syntax. But I'll recommend to use `ANSI SQL-92` syntax. Example of that is below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p 
         INNER JOIN features f 
                ON p.id = f.id 
         INNER JOIN attributes a 
                ON p.id = a.id
where p.id =1
```

in that way you have to explicitly define their relationship (*the `ON` clause*) in order to avoid syntax error. The `ANSI SQL-89` syntax is prone to error and you might not notice it because it will not produce an error. Example

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p, features f, attributes a
where p.id =1
```

Without defining the relationship field, it will still execute but gives you invalid result. From `INNER JOIN`, it is now `CROSS JOIN`

***Additional Information***

**[Read something here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768587/on-is-part-of-syntax/11768715#11768715)** 
        **[MySQL JOIN Tutorials](http://mysqljoin.com/)**

Comment: +1 Great bit of info, I always thought that the older format was the newer.

Answer (score 1):

This is inner join, if you also want to get the products without features or attributes, you need to use `LEFT JOIN`. And you need to use the foreign key for join, like `p.feature_id` and `p.attribute_id` .

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN features f ON p.feature_id = f.id
LEFT JOIN attributes a ON p.attribute_id = a.id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make it easier to read by writing the joins as ANSI (I know, cue the ANSI vs older syntax comments :) )

```
select 
    * 
from 
    products p
        left join features f
            on p.id=f.id
        left join attributes a
            on p.id=a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite, you have the values reversed

```
SELECT * FROM
  products   p,
  features   f,
  attributes a
WHERE
  p.id = 1    AND
  f.id = p.id AND
  a.id = p.id
```

But, it wont do what your asking of it, it would be better to perform three queries here IMO.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Inner join for such type of requirements where you have to fetch the data of all three tables.for example:

```
SELECT p.prduct_id,p.product_name,a.attribute,f.feature
      FROM product AS p
      INNER JOIN attribute AS a ON ( p.product_id = a.attribute_id ) 
      INNER JOIN feature AS f ON ( a.id = f.feature_id )
```

like that above query you should have foreign key in attribute and feature table from the parent table product.