# SQL: Show value of column A if value of column B matches column B in another table

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, there are many similar topics but still can't seem to find an answer to mine.
I hope some one can help me here, here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a table called **"brand"** and a table called **"product"**
I'm trying to build a query which will show the product_id from table **"product"** if the brand_id in that table is the same as the brand_id in table **"brand"**.

So basically I have, brand table:

```
brand_name    brand_id
a             1
b             2
c             3
```

and product table:

```
product_id    brand_id
23            2
24            1
25            2
27            3 
28            3
```

Now if the brand_id 3 is selected I want to show all the product_id with brand_id 3 in.

I have so far:

```
SELECT brand_id, brand_name, from " . TABLE_BRAND . " order by brand_name";

SELECT product_id from " . TABLE_PRODUCT . where brand_id = '" . (int)$brands['brand_id'] . "'");
```

Would anyone be able to help me get this to work like I described, please?
Regards

Comment: Look up "inner join" on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll recommend you to use `ANSI SQL-92` syntax rather than `ANSI SQL-89` syntax because  if not properly joined results to `CROSS JOIN`. **[Read something HERE: ANSI SQL-92 INNER JOIN.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768715/491243)**

```
SELECT  a.Product_ID, b.brand_name
FROM    `product` a 
            INNER JOIN  `brand` b
                ON a.brand_id = b.brand_ID
-- WHERE a.Product_ID = valueHERE       -- <== place condition here :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
SELECT
    b.brand_name,
    p.product_id
FROM
    brand AS b,
    product AS p
WHERE
    b.brand_id = p.brand_id
```

Comment: FROM brand as b INNER JOIN product as p ON b.brand_id=p.brand_id WHERE b.brand_id = <brand id here>

Comment: @vtonehundred . . . if you are going to answer a question, please use the correct join syntax ("join" keyword, "on" statement).

Comment: @GordonLinoff this is also a valid syntax but an old one and which is also prone to lead `cross join`. right? :)

Comment: @JohnTotetWoo . . . In the current SQL standard, "," means cross join.  Cross join can be very expensive (performance-wise), and a comma is easy to miss.  If you leave out the comma, the second table can become an alias for the first table, introducing another source of error.  The intention of this query is to do an inner join.  The inner join should be specified in the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Point taken, but my syntax is still perfectly acceptable in at least PostgreSQL and MySQL.  But yes, I see and don't disagree with your point.  :)